# Can I use CORS to view an XML file that references an XSLT on a remote server?

Tags: xml, xslt, cors, same-origin-policy

I'm aware of the [Same-Origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) issues of serving content that references content on another server.  However, I found [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and was hoping it would do what I want.  I haven't yet had any luck mainly because I don't fully understand it.  I'm also having a hard time finding examples of CORS and XML/XSLT.

Here is what I have done:

**1. Added the following to my web.config**

```
  <httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
   </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

**2. Created the following XML file called `hello.xml` and uploaded it to scott.host/**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://scott.host/hello.xsl"?>
 <hello-world>   <greeter>An XSLT Programmer</greeter>   <greeting>Hello, World!</greeting></hello-world>
```

**3. Created the following XSL file called `hello.xsl` and uploaded it to another domain (same server)**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/hello-world">
     <HTML>
       <HEAD>
         <TITLE></TITLE>
       </HEAD>
       <BODY>
         <H1>
           <xsl:value-of select="greeting"/>
         </H1>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="greeter"/>
       </BODY>
     </HTML>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="greeter">
     <DIV>from <I><xsl:value-of select="."/></I></DIV>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I access `http://scott.host/hello.xml` it displays properly, with the transform, as expected.  However, when I access `http://otherdomain/hello.xml` I get the `Request for cross-domain XSLT was denied` error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Note: I have disabled the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` entry in my webconfig after posting this.

References:

- [CORS on IIS7](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html)
- [Hello, World! (XSLT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765388(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Sorry about the nested code within a quote, it wasn't showing up at all with just a code block.

Comment: Removed the quote blocks and it's showing up fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have tested, the support depends on the browser, Mozilla browsers do support it, as with http://home.versanet.de/~martin-honnen/xslt/test2015070201.xml the stylesheet from http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/cdtest/test2015070201.xsl is applied by Firefox, while IE (tested with IE 11) says

> Die Anforderung für domänenübergreifendes XSLT wurde verweigert."
>   ("The request for a cross-domain XSLT was refused")

and Chrome also gives a similar error

> Unsafe attempt to load URL
>   http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/cdtest/test2015070201.xsl from
>   frame with URL
>   http://home.versanet.de/~martin-honnen/xslt/test2015070201.xml.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: That's too bad.  The spec I saw said it worked in IE10+, Chrome 3+ and FF.

Comment: I think doing CORS based `XMLHttpRequest` in Javascript  has better support than XSLT doing it.